# Ways to format one-liner JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, aptana, code-formatting, aptana3

What are some of the best and quickest ways to format a JavaScript file.
I ask because I've downloaded a file called slides.min.jquery.js and I
would like to know how to change it so instead of being a one-liner it
is formatted properly.

I've got Aptana Studio but don't know how to open a JavaScript Project.
Any ideas? Thanks. Or else another tool will do.

Thanks.

Comment: you can beautify using http://danml.com/slim/ , under [Tools]

Answer (score 4):

You can use a tool like [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) to de-minify the compressed js.

Firefox has a plugin called [deminifyer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/javascript-deminifier/eula/141018) which can be used for this purpose as an offline solution.

Comment: Is there an offline solution (an installed application)?

Comment: There is a ff plugin which can be used offline. Just edited the answer